# How to save multiple inputs in different formats?

Tags: matlab, function, input

Here is my code:

```
angles = 'Please enter the Euler angles in degrees- yaw(x),pitch(y) and roll(z) \n:';
ea = input(angles,'s');
cos(ea(1))
```

This code saves the elements of the input string 'ea' as char. How should I save the input in degrees directly?
Using cos(ea(1)) gives an error:

```
Undefined function 'cos' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the input function returns a string, so you will need to convert that to a numerical value. Secondly cos takes input in radians not degrees, so you will either need to convert to radians or to use `cosd` instead of `cos`.

```
angles = 'Please enter the Euler angles in degrees- yaw(x),pitch(y) and roll(z) \n:';
ea = str2double(input(angles,'s'));
cosd(ea(1))
```

You can also use `input` without the `'s'` parameter. In that case input will evaluate the expression passed as a string and return the result. For example in that case not only can you pass singles values such as '90' but you could also pass things like: 3*180/4 as input

```
angles = 'Please enter the Euler angles in degrees- yaw(x),pitch(y) and roll(z) \n:';
ea = input(angles);
cosd(ea(1))
```

Comment: Nice example! As we all know `x*180/4` is the formula for converting `x` from radians to degrees, for `pi=4`.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `input(prompt,'s')`, you're specifically telling it to return the user input as string. You need to drop the `'s'` to get numeric input. Also, you need to do `input` three times to actually get three inputs. Use a structure to store the input in different fields because it can take string as a field name. It's more organized and easily understandable.

```
prompt = 'Please enter Euler angles in degress, ';
choice = {'yaw(x): ', 'pitch(y): ', 'roll(z): '};

for ii = 1 : numel(choice)
    ea.(choice{ii}(1:end-5)) = input([prompt, choice{ii}]);
end
```

But of course, this will also work :

```
for ii = 1 : numel(choice)
    ea(ii) = input([prompt, choice{ii}]);
end
```